# Какими командами можно скачивать через приложение на Java

Tags: java

Например, есть у меня приложение со своим дизайном и мне через него нужно скачать файл в интернете, как мне это реализовать?

Comment: А как вы пытались это реализовать и с какими сложностями столкнулись? Из вопроса не понятно, какие именно данные вы скачиваете и что хотите с ними сделать. Вот здесь можете подсмотреть  как получать данные из сети https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection

Comment: Зависит от того, по какому протоколу отдаёт его сервер. Если это что-то нестандартное, придётся писать свой алгоритм на сокетах. Если например HTTP, то можно воспользоваться соответствующим методом класса [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), [HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html)'ом или любыми другими подобными средствами. Аналогично для других протоколов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто отправляешь запрос на скачивание. Первый попавшийся вариант, который я загуглил

```
try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(FILE_URL).openStream());
  FileOutputStream fileOutputStream new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME)) {
    byte dataBuffer[] = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = in.read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
        fileOutputStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Comment: не робит, я прописал все, ссылку на картинку прописал там, и имя файла дал, нихера не скачалось -____-

Comment: Проблема может быть в чем угодно. Может для скачивания с данного адреcа нужно залогиниться, или используется другой HTTP метод, или что-то ещё

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%82&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX_5jcpt_iAhW6isMKHV0tDFIQ_AUIEygE&biw=1366&bih=657#imgrc=IggA6fwsM5nsVM: Данная ссылка должна подойти, и все должно загрузиться